# Selecting Last x Children in Jsoup

Tags: select, jsoup, children

I'm trying to get last x rows (in this case, last 5 rows) of a table using Jsoup. But before picking last 5 children, I need to apply some filters to selector query.

```
Elements ptr = ptable.select("tr:gt(0):contains("+patern+")");
```

This is what I must select first. Because table contains lots of unnecessary rows, I filter first row (which contains titles of the columns) and to get rid of useless rows, I use patern text to pick what I need. (this part works without a problem)

After this step I need to get last 5 results from the remaining elements. I tried this

```
Elements ptr = ptable.select("tr:gt(0):contains("+patern+"):nth-last-child(-n+5)");
```

But it didn't work. Tried nth-last-child(5) but still not working. As a last result I tried ;

```
Elements ptd = ptr.select("td:nth-last-child(-n+"+Integer.toString(ptd1.size()*5)+")");
```

To pick results as td's but still didn't work. 
("ptd1.size()" returns column count.)

Well, in the end I have failed to get last 5 elements after applying the filters I want. Is there anyway to select them after I apply filters "gt(0)" and "contains("+patern+")" ?

ps. Table content is dynamic, so I can't skip first x rows in order to get last 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a sublist from the filtered list of matching elements. I've wrote a simple example in Groovy - https://gist.github.com/wololock/ade801b2ccf65f21de4d What you can see there is that in the first place you filter out all rows that you are not interested in:

```
Elements elements = document.select('table#test tr:contains(ID)')
```

In this example we are not interested in rows that does not contain the "ID" keyword for simplicity. Then we just take the last n elements from our list of filtered elements:

```
int numberOfLastElements = 3
List<Element> sublist = elements.subList(elements.size() - numberOfLastElements, elements.size())
```

Be aware that in your code you will have to check if the number of filtered elements is greater than the number you tried to extract - without it you will run into ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. The last thing we check in that code is if the result contains the elements we expect:

```
assert sublist.every {
    ['ID: 4', 'ID: 5', 'ID: 6'].contains(it.select('td:first-child').html())
}
```

This simple assertion is added for test purpose and you should not add it to your production code. It only checks if every element in filtered sublist contains one of the given contents in the first td element.

This example is written in Groovy, the Java solution will be almost the same.

Comment: I have used this code `Elements sublist = (Elements) ptr.subList(ptr.size() - 5, ptr.size());` but i got this error. Am I doing something wrong? `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractListRandomAccess cannot be cast to org.jsoup.select.Elements`

Comment: It was my mistake - in Java it should be like `List<Element> sublist = ptr.subList(ptr.size() - 5, ptr.size());`. Groovy does well with casting in this case (`List<Element> -> Elements` thanks its dynamic language improvements) but in Java it has to be statically correct. I've fixed the answer and code sample in Gist. Sorry for inconvenience.